# Combining python and JS (mapbox) for interactive rendering

Tags: javascript, python, maps, mapbox

I plan on visualising a huge dataset (probably around 20-30GB of data) using Mapbox in order to have a very nice map visualization. However I would like this visualization to be interactive and I am pretty sure that both JS and my browser will not really like such an amount of data, so I wanted to have my data filtering/processing operations conducted with python and the rendering done dynamically with JS and Mapbox.

I have seen that there is Python API for Mapbox, but all of the examples I have seen so far of it simply create a geojson dataset once and a html page, but it seems that the rendering code in JS is not dynamically generated. What I am looking for on the other hand is more of a kind of rendering done by JS while the data filtering/computation is achieved by python, so that there would be some dynamic communication between the two. Would you guys know if there is any way to achieve that? Is it also likely to be too slow anyway even if all of the data processing/filtering is done with python (if that is possible)?

Comment: Is your data really so big? You could check how much is the output in another format: [Managing large data](https://www.mapbox.com/help/large-data-tippecanoe/). This is useful for [doing tiling on the server](https://www.mapbox.com/help/working-with-large-geojson-data/)

Comment: Yes I mean a simple csv will be like 30GB in the end :-)

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125037/self-hosting-mapbox-vector-tiles)?

Comment: @juvian now I have. But I mean I suppose that if I have such a big dataset JS in anyway is not going to be helpful right ? Even if I managed to do just the rendering, streaming huge convos of data between JS and python or C++ would still be too slow don’t you think ?

Comment: When you move around mapbox, requests are made for data from your server. This is based on 3 coordinates, x y and z. You choose how to serve them. If you have a file for each tile coordinate, you can just read that file and return that data, so instead of having all in a big 30gb file, you load smaller files on demand

Comment: @juvian I guess that could work, but I have high dimensional data over several time steps, so even this elegant solution might not work in the end... I should probably try it out though

Comment: You should first try to use better format from my first links, geojson is horribly big as its repeats too much